# How To Automate Finding Coordinates For Details in Photos - openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a bunch of images (attached below). I have a sign in each image and I want to extract the signs using openCV. However, I have no clue about how to accomplish this and I don't have any code as well. Does anybody have any ballpark ideas to separately take each of these images and automatically remove the signs, and have it generalized in case I add more images similar to the example images given below.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

[image: Example 4]

Example of sign image:

[image: Example of sign image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I already commented to your first question - Stackoverflow is no code-writing service. Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far? What do you expect? What error do you get? For help, take a look at [ask] or consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Only thing I've tried is contouring but the images are so vastly different that I can't simply isolate the signs like I need.

Comment: I tested OCR using [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) and I was able to extract the numbers of every image you provided. If you really need the borders of the signs you could then save the provided coordinates of the bounding box (in the json file) and run some kind of floodfill/watershed to segment your sign in your original image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will work.

**Limitation:**
This solution assumes that the sign always contains numbers. If this is not the case, this might not work.

Set `gpu` flag to false if it is not available.

```
import cv2
from easyocr import Reader

image = cv2.imread("./image/path/image.jpg")

languages = ['en']
reader = Reader(languages, gpu = True)
results = reader.readtext(image)

def cleanup_text(text):
    return "".join([c if ord(c) < 128 else "" for c in text]).strip()

for (bbox, text, prob) in results:

        text = cleanup_text(text)

        if text.isnumeric():
                print(bbox)
                (tl, tr, br, bl) = bbox
                tl = (int(tl[0]), int(tl[1]))
                tr = (int(tr[0]), int(tr[1]))
                br = (int(br[0]), int(br[1]))
                bl = (int(bl[0]), int(bl[1]))
                
                cv2.rectangle(image, tl, br, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv2.putText(image, text, (tl[0], tl[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Sign", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Output:]

**Credit:**
The code for displaying bounding boxes and cleaning text is obtained from this [blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/09/14/getting-started-with-easyocr-for-optical-character-recognition/).

Comment: Thanks for showing me this method, it does seem very useful. Is there anyway of fulfilling the operations of the easyocr module through openCV though?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no methods in openCV to perform effective recognition. There are some methods that can be tweaked to perform text detection and recognition (e.g., EAST  + template matching), but they have limitations. You will have to use other libraries, such as `easyocr` or `Tesseract` to do text recognition.